# ITK ScalarImageToCooccurrenceMatrixFilter function has same results

Tags: 3d, itk

I use ITK `ScalarImageToCooccurrenceMatrixFilter` function extract 3D CT DICOM, but I get the same result, I change window's size or change another series, the result also is the same, could anyone point me to a solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

ITK `ScalarImageToCooccurrenceMatrixFilter` won't work for pixels of double or long-double type, so I converted data type to unsigned char, and it's working.